# Understanding my father's Army service records (1946-1948)

Tags: 20th-century, military-records, united-kingdom, army

I have obtained the army service records for my father (he did his national service between 1946 and 1948.)

Not unexpectedly, the documents contain a wealth of abbreviations (or possibly acronyms) and Army terms and reference numbers. Rather than googling for each and every one and hoping to strike lucky, or asking for an expert to interpret the whole document, is there a comprehensive reference source I can use to interpret the material myself (and maybe return here with any really tricky points).

If it matters, the documents I have are

- Army form B.102
- Army form B.103-1 (Service and Casualty Form)
- Notification of Impending Release PART I
- Army Form B.200d (second Revise.) (Territorial Army Record of Service Paper)

Comment: Wondering if you were able to make any progress with this despite not getting any answers? I don't know of any comprehensive resource, likely because due to the date these records are not yet widely accessible.

Comment: @HarryVervet Not yet -- I've picked the bones out of the records, but I'm sure there would be so much more to understand if only I could. I know have my grandfather's service records (1932-1946) to understand as well, and there's even more abbreviations in those.

Comment: Did you try the [DOD Dictionary of Military and Associated Terms](http://www.dtic.mil/doctrine/new_pubs/dictionary.pdf) Kurt

Comment: Wrong country, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

The [Ministry of Defence Acronyms and Abbreviations](http://www.gov.uk/government/publications/ministry-of-defence-acronyms-and-abbreviations) page is probably the most definitive reference source that I'll find. It was issued in 2014 and provides:

> Definitions for terms and acronyms used throughout MOD documents.